# pass data via. navigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

i'm trying to pass Data to a viewController. The problem is that its embedded in a navigationController and is presented modally. How can i pass to a viewController which is presented modally and is embedded in a navigation Controller

```
func offerNew(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    let offerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OfferViewController") as UINavigationController


    self.presentViewController(offerVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

i've tried this

```
    let offerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("offerNavigation") as UINavigationController
    let targetVC = offerVC.topViewController as OfferViewController
    self.presentViewController(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that offerVC is the navigationController in which your "target" view controller is embedded.  If so, your target view controller can be accessed through the `topViewController` property of offerVC.  So

```
let targetVC = offerVC.topViewController as TargetViewController
```

will give you a reference.  You can then access the properties of your target view controller.

**EDIT**

But you should present OfferVC - it will display targetVC automatically.

```
self.presentViewController(offerVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Comment: Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: Are you presenting targetVC, or offerVC?

Comment: i'm presenting the targetVC

Comment: You should present OfferVC.  It will automatically present targetVC.  You only need targetVC if you want to set any properties beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to your `OfferViewController`, then assign it. Your view initialization code would be done in `loadView`, which won't be called until after presentViewController, so not having it during `init` shouldn't be a problem in most cases.